# MacBook Pro | Screen Brightness not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display

I recently got a a MacBook Pro early 2011 and I am not able to change the brightness, either higher or lower. The brightness keys don't work and the brightness setting in System Preferences > Displays, doesn't appear to show. I have to change the settings for the brightness keys but still it doesn't seem work. What should I do to fix this?

[image]